# Regex doesnt work with re.findall

Tags: python, regex

I have a unicode string of the format

I have this unicode string :

```
unistr= [something::a.b.c][someotherthing::e.f.g]
```

I tried to write a regex that takes in only the strings before and after the `"::"` delimiter.
I tried testing this regex: `([\w\.]).+?(?=\:\:)` with my string in an online regex builder and it gave me out the desired result.

However when I wrapped it within this re.findall function, it doesn't give me the same result. it gives out [c,g]
This is what I tried:

```
re.findall(r'([\w\.]).+?(?=\:\:)',unistr) #to get the string before "::"
re.findall(r'.+?([\w\.]\:\:)',unistr) # to get after "::"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not simply `re.findall(r'(\w+)::', unistr)`? This will return "something". Note that ":" shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: Is that `unistr=` part of the string? Or is there supposed to be triple quotes after the `=` and after the second line? Or…?

Comment: Also, is your online regex builder using Python syntax?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Can you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @Tania I posted it, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't complicate things, this will work:

```
re.findall(r'(\w+)::', unistr)
```

It matches word characters followed by `::` and captures it, returns a list containing all matches.

Note that `:` is not a special character, shouldn't be escaped.

Comment: Elegant. Simple yet spot on. Thanks @Maroun

Comment: @Tania I'm glad it helped :) please visit the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I think you tested it wrong somehow. I modified it with this expression: `([\w\.])+` instead on [Pythex](http://pythex.org/) and it captured two groups, `someotherstring` and `e.f.g`, which is what I think you want, right?

Comment: AGain gives out only the last two characters

Comment: Yes. exactly. Thanks for suggestng Pythex. I was using regexpr

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `finditer` with `([^\[]*)\:{2}([^\]]*)` regex to get the `::`-delimited contents inside the square brackets:

```
import re
unistr = u'unistr= [something::a.b.c]'
print [[x.group(1), x.group(2)] for x in re.finditer(ur'([^\[]*)\:{2}([^\]]*)',unistr)]
```

Output of a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNGpiZm9iUVhidDA):

```
[[u'something', u'a.b.c']]
```

Comment: By the way, if you are testing regular expressions online, http://regex101.com is a great resource for python regexes.

Comment: Great.Thanks for suggesting!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
import re
unistr= 'something::a.b.c'
print re.findall(r'^.+?(?=::)',unistr)
print re.findall(r'(?<=::).+?$',unistr)
```

Output:

```
['something']                                                                
['a.b.c']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
unistr= '[something::a.b.c][someotherthing::e.f.g]'
map(lambda v: v.split('::'), re.findall(r'\w+\:\:[\w\.]+', unistr))
```

Output:

```
Out[412]:
[['something', 'a.b.c'], ['someotherthing', 'e.f.g']]
```